# Django: get table name of a model in the model manager?

Tags: django

I have a model and have a model manager for this model. I'm writing some sql in the model manager, and I need the table name of the model in sql. I know the name of table is combined by metadata app_label and db_name, but is it possible that I can access them from manager class? I know I can create an model instance in the manager, but I would rather not do that..

Thanks very much!

Comment: Only tangentially related to the original question (and the various methods in the answers), but if `_meta.db_table` is giving you a relation-does-not-exist error, you may have a mixed-case app or table name, and may need quotes around the table name.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55297807/when-do-postgres-column-or-table-names-need-quotes-and-when-dont-they or

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Model manager has the field `model`:

```
Model.objects.model._meta.db_table
```

Comment: Why not just `Model._meta.db_table` ?

Comment: Pycharm annoying me because `Access to a protected member _meta of a class `

Answer (score 14):

For a given `instance`, you can use `instance._meta.db_table` but that also works for the model class too, so if you can step up from the manager to its `model`, that'll work too

Answer (score 11):

Let's say you have a model named `Service`

You can use

```
Service._meta.db_table # this will work too
```

This as well

```
Service.objects.model._meta.db_table # this will work too
```

This as well 
Let's say you had an instance of the service `Model` like this

```
service = Service.objects.get(pk=1)
# get table name like this
table_name = service._meta.db_table # this will work too
```