# How to specify names for implicit many-to-many relation table columns in Prisma?

Tags: prisma

I have this Prisma schema with a many to many relation between Authors and Posts:

```
datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

generator client {
  provider        = "prisma-client-js"
  binaryTargets   = ["native"]
}

model Author {
  id    String    @id
  posts Post[]    @relation(name: "AuthorPostRelation")
}

model Post {
  id        String      @id
  authors   Author[]    @relation(name: "AuthorPostRelation")
}
```

Prisma (version 3.11.0) generates a table for the implicit relation with field `A` referencing `Author`s `id` and with field `B` referencing `Post`'s `id`.

Is there a way to specify custom names for the relation table? E.g. `author` instead of `A` and `post` instead of `B`?

EDIT: I am aware that specifying custom field names is possible with explicit relation tables, but I'm specifically interested in implicit relation tables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible yet to specify columns names in implicit relation tables.

For implicit relations, you need to adhere to the conventions of `A` and `B` as the table names.

However, this could possibly change in future and there is this [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/4301) that tracks this.